# @PropertyName saves data but won't retrieve it with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, serialization

```
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName

data class MyClass(
  @PropertyName(value = "n") 
  val name: String = "",
)
```

It works when you save data. On my database, the name was saved with the key "n", but when trying to get it, it's not read and I get an empty string because of the default constructor unless I change the actual name of the field to "n" which works in that case.

I'm using the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the `name` property as `n`, and you also want to read it as an `n`, then you have to explicitly add the annotation for both `set` and `get` in front of the property. So in your case, that would be:

```
data class MyClass(
    @get:PropertyName("n")
    @set:PropertyName("n")
    var name: String = ""
)
```

Comment: Can't do that as the `val` indicates it's immutable. Compilation error `'@set:' annotations could be applied only to mutable properties`

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. It should be var. Please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in my updated answer, does it work for you?

Comment: It does work if I change it from value to variable and adding the @set property. Do you happen to know if this is done by design or if it is a bug? It's not ideal to be forced to change something from immutable to mutable just for it to be de/serialized properly.

Comment: This is how Kotlin works.